# Multiplying pixel value XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing a WPF app. For fun I've overwritten the styling to match Material-UI styling, so I defined a bunch of Styles in the App.xaml file so that they can be referenced everywhere throughout the app.

I'm try to add support for selecting the DP for the app, i.e. hdpi, xhdpi, etc, through the App.config file. Basically to do this I need to multiply a default pixel value with a modifier. But I'm not sure how to do that using XAML. I assume I need to have some sort of Binding with the App.xaml.cs file but nothing seems to work.

Currently I have something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="muiTextFields_TextBox">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"/>
  ...
</Style>
```

I would need something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="muiTextFields_TextBox">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32 * <some multiplier>"/>
  ...
</Style>
```

I've tried using `Binding`s but the App.xaml.cs class doesn't support `this.DataContext`...

Comment: WPF is always DPI aware an auto-adjust you shouldn't have anything to code if you've done your window properly.

Comment: I see... I guess my understanding is wrong. Thanks, I'll read up on it!